# Javascript Add Current Domain Name to URL Parameter

Tags: javascript

How can I retreive a domain name of the current page with javascript, and add it to url parameter like this before redirecting:

http://redirecturl.com?domain={domain}

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy answer below.  However, I little research would have yielded the same without **stackoverflow**

```js
let url = `http://redirecturl.com?domain=${document.location.hostname}`;
console.log( url );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `location.hostname`:

```js
const redirectURL = `http://redirecturl.com?domain=${location.hostname}`;
console.log(redirectURL);
```

ES5:

```js
var redirectURL = "http://redirecturl.com?domain=" + location.hostname;
console.log(redirectURL);
```

---

Note: The above return `stacksnippets.net` because that's where StackOverflow run their snippets (as you will see if you [visit the website](https://stacksnippets.net)